# Mathematica, Fibonacci sequence using While and Module commands

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, while-loop

How can i write a program that computes f[n] (for Fibonacci numbers:f[n]=f[n]-f[n-2], with f[0] = any number) **using `Module` and a `While` loop**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homework?  I hope you learn by example. ;-)

Your subject line says recursion, but you don't specify that in your question; rather, you specify `Module` and `While`.  I'll go with the latter.

```
fib[n_] := 
  Module[{x = 1, y = 0, i = 0},
    While[i++ < n, {x, y} = {y, x + y}];
    y
  ]

Array[fib, 7]

(*  Out[]= {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13}  *)

Table[fib[m], {m, 1,10}] 

(*  Out[]= {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55}  *)
```

Comment: haha nah the homework sequence question is harder then a fibonacci sequence?

Comment: What if we had to input table[fib[m],{1,10}] ?

Comment: @Sunday really just joking about the homework thing, but your question does seem strangely specific.  Why not something like: "what are some good ways to generate the Fibonacci sequence in Mathematica, without using Fibonacci[x]?"  ?   Anyway, I just updated my answer with a cleaner version.

Comment: @Sunday You're welcome.  If you find an answer helpful, please give it an up vote (the triangle above the number to the left).  If an answer is fully satisfactory, please also "accept" it by clicking the check mark.  You can and should up vote all answers that are helpful, but you may only "accept" one answer.  However, you may change which answer you accept at any time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  +1 For `Array[fib,7]`. Nice. Works a little like `Table`but I suspect there are some additional benefits, right?

Comment: @David `Array` is more direct, since you are giving arguments directly, rather than by named iterators.  This makes it clearer for multi-dimentional specifications, like `Array[x, {2, 4, 3}]`, but less flexible.  For example, with `Table` iterators can be interdependent (`Table[j, {i, 7}, {j, i}]`), and have skips (`Table[i, {i, 2, 12, 2}]`) while `Array` cannot.  You can specify a starting index or "origin" however.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I found the explanation helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to impress your instructor, I would use the memory cache approach. It is significantly faster than the approach Sjoerd is describing.

Consider this implementation

```
fib[0]:=1
fib[1]:=1
fib[n_]:= (fib[n]=fib[n-1]+fib[n-2])
```

Lets compare the two, just to prove my point.

```
slowfib[0]:=1
slowfib[1]:=1
slowfib[n_]:=slowfib[n-1]+slowfib[n-2]
```

Here's the comparison in runtimes:

```
Map[fib, Range[30]] // AbsoluteTiming

{0.000158, {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 
  987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 
  121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269}}

Map[slowfib, Range[30]] // AbsoluteTiming

{6.582185, {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 
987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 
121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269}}
```

The runtime is so much higher because the recursive function

```
fib[n_]:=fib[n-1]+fib[n-2]
```

generates n^2 recursive calls (write it out on paper if that doesn't make sense). On the other hand, defining

```
fib[n_]:= fib[n]=fib[n-1]+fib[n-2]
```

takes advantage of memory caching to calculate the terms, which results in a drastically faster runtime, since each call generates a cached value for fib[x].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Memoization is indeed advantageous, but this does not use `Module` or `While` as the OP requested.

Comment: @keshav Of course, the mma documentation makes this abundantly clear. I didn't want to complicate matters by adding this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The OP asks for recursion in the title, which is clearly contradictory with the other requirements of While&Module. So you have to choose for either of them.

Comment: @Sjoerd, that is true, but, if you will pardon me, Sunday selected my answer, so I presume I guessed right.

Comment: @Keshav Saharia In really the recursive function generates `Exp[n/2]` recursive calls: `slowfib[0] = 1;
slowfib[1] = 1;
slowfib[n_] := (++i; slowfib[n - 1] + slowfib[n - 2]); g = ListLinePlot[tb = Table[i = 0; slowfib[n]; {n, i}, {n, 2, 25}]]; fun = FindFit[tb, a Exp[k n], {a, k}, n]; Show[g, Plot[a Exp[k t] /. fun, {t, 2, 25}, PlotStyle -> Black]]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Might be, but I feel Sunday just pressed the wrong button ;^)

Answer (score 1):

Going by the first part of your title, the following approach would be an example of how to do that:

```
fib[1] = 1; 
fib[2] = 1; 
fib[n_] := fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]

fib[3]
fib[7]

Out[11]= 2

Out[12]= 13

fib /@ Range[20]

Out[10]= {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 
610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181,  6765}
```